# android-support-v7-appcompat.jar not installed?

Tags: android, libraries

I downloaded the latest version of eclipse and anndroid 5 and the supporting libraries. Now I can't find android-support-v7-appcompat.jar. I wonder if I mistakenly deleted it?

I wonder if I should go back and reinstall the libraries, or?

Comment: `appcompat-v7` is not a JAR. It is an Android library project.

Comment: You have to **import** the `android-support-v7-appcompat` **project** into your workspace.

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned in the comments to the OP appcompat v7 needs to be imported and built. Then it should be referenced by your project as a library.

https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html